# Upvote/Downvote Text on Questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When you hover over the upvote and downvote buttons on a question, it says:

> **Upvote:** This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear
>   **Downvote:** This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

These do not seem to be relevant to the Puzzling community and its goals.

Can the text be changed, should it be changed, and if so, what to?

Comment: [Related post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8362/38979) on Codegolf (who have the same problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We do not have any direct control over it, and I don't think it's possible for *any* site to change it.

Comment: Or a passerby SO multi-site moderator may chime in and evaluate that feature request.