# Broad flag text

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The text to flag a question as too broad is currently:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Like [my previous meta question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5755/upvote-downvote-text-on-questions), this also seems to be unfitting with the goals of Puzzling.

Should this be changed, can it be changed, and if so, what to?

For example:

> There are either too many possible solutions, or good solutions would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the solution set so that the puzzle can be solved and explained in (some size of text).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We cannot change flag text, except under the "off-topic" section. As you can see, we have already added a "not fully defined" close reason - we've had it for years.

[image]

In practical use, "too broad" covers it most of the time, *and* it gives more than a generic message in the "closed by" box. It's also more easily visible, so more users use it as a close reason.